# Vuejs В каком хуке проверять аутентификацию пользователя, чтобы роутер успевал перенаправить?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Отправляю запрос на локальный сервер в главном компоненте App.vue, но запрос, как я понимаю, не успевает прийти, и если даже сервер подтверждает аутентификацию пользователя, то его всё равно кидает на страницу с логином.
Вопрос такой, в каком хуке проверять аутентификацию пользователя, чтобы роутер успевал перенаправить?

Answer (score 0):

```
// main.js
// Где-то в коде вы получаете профиль пользователя, загружаете в store и т.п. 
const fetchUserProfile = () => Promise.resolve({ username: 'FooBar' })

;(async () => {
  try {
    const profile = await fetchUserProfile()
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
})()

// На данный момент профиль загружен
app.use(router)
app.mount('#')

//,,,
```

Еще есть вариант посмотреть в сторону хуков на стороне роутера https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html